# UIApplication shortcut with custom launch screen

Tags: ios, launch-screen, uiapplicationshortcutitem

I've implemented [shortcut support](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/adding-3d-touch-quick-actions.html) in my iOS app, so you can "force touch" the icon and jump directly to various points.

When you do this, the application's ["launch screen" storyboard](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-a-launch-screen-storyboard.html) is briefly shown, and then the target view controller appears.

In this App, the target scenes contrast very strongly with the launch scene's appearance. This looks a bit naff and I'd like to improve it.

Is it possible to prevent the launch screen showing while the shortcut is being presented? Or can I provide a custom launch screen for use with shortcuts?

N.B. This happens both when the application is already launched (and the shortcut is awaking it from the background), on also on first launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't believe you can do it (easily at least). When in doubt, see what Apple do on their own apps and I haven't seen them do something similar to what you propose, though I do like the idea!

Perhaps you should look at making your launch screen more general? A lot of the apps I've worked on have been very boring, but it's nice to see things like this challenged. If you want to attach screenshots or drawings for us to help you with your designs then that's fine, we'll do our best ;) Or submit a Bug Report/Feature Request with Apple?

Comment: Hi there – that's my conclusion too. I've had a look at existing shortcut enabled apps and they all seem to show the same launch screen when you use a short cut. Good call with submitting a bug report. I've wanted contextual launch screens before, so this is another example of that. Probably quite a tough thing to do given that the App hasn't got itself together when the launch screen is needed, though. However, the shortcuts could describe the launch screen they want, and other ways of launching apps (urls & resuming) could probably provide a static description of this too. Would be nice :-)